# TSQL: Prevent Nulls update over existing data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

1. Orders (Table I update and want keep existing data, and prevent overwriting with nulls)
2. WRK_Table (This table is identical to *Orders* but can not guarantee all columns will have data when running update)

PK column 'Master_Ordernum'
There are many columns in the tables, the WRK_Table will have the PK, but data in other columns can not be counted on.

I want the WRK_Table to update Orders only with actual data and not Nulls.
I was thinking along this line:

```
UPDATE [Orders] 
SET [Status] = CASE WHEN S.[Status] IS NOT NULL THEN S.[Status] END 
FROM [WRK_TABLE] S
WHERE [Orders].[Master_Ordernum] = S.[Master_Ordernum]
```

The existing data in Orders is being updated with nulls

Comment: What will happen is in your query, it will insert rows with data no problem, but what will happen with a NULL row is that it will go through your case statement, not meet any of the requirements, and then since there's no ELSE, return NULL. Exactly what you don't want. You're going to want to filter your columns like how Steve Drake does it in his answer.

Comment: I'm in the process of updating my statement along the lines of Wendy's suggestion now.  Small testing looked good.  I'm hoping the impact of expanding to 100+ columns in some cases isn't to bad considering its part of a recurring SSIS package.  I'm hoping to not have to link tables if needed.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
update orders set name = work.name 
from orders 
inner join work on orders.id = work.id and work.Name is not null
```

Not the same col / table name but you should get the idea

*EDIT*

Your SQL, NOT TESTED

```
UPDATE Orders
SET [Status] = WRK_Table.[Status]
FROM [Orders] 
inner join WRK_Table  on [Orders].[Master_Ordernum] = [WRK_Table].[Master_Ordernum] and WRK_Table.[Status] is not null
```

If you want to test and undo your data just do something like (assuming you don't have 100s of rows)

```
begin tran
```

/* .. SQL THAT UPDATES ... */

```
select * from orders // review the data

rollback tran // Undo changes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a Case statement, you need to include an else to prevent it from just inserting that null. Try this - if the work table has a null, let it just overwrite the value with the existing value.

```
UPDATE [Orders] 
SET [Status] = CASE WHEN S.[Status] IS NOT NULL THEN S.[Status] else [Orders].[Status] END 
FROM [WRK_TABLE] S
WHERE [Orders].[Master_Ordernum] = S.[Master_Ordernum]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use

```
Update my_table set col = ISNULL(@newval,@existingval) where id=@id
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).